# Chartist-js X and Y scale colour

Tags: graph, charts, colors, chartist.js

Does anybody know how to change the grey x and y scale to black in the JavaScript graphing library `chartist-js`? I've looked in the CSS file but I can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

In Chartist.css, Search for .ct-label, and change last value in rgba, which is the opacity value between 0 and 1. E.g to:

```
.ct-label {
fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); }
```